# How to make function return reports based on report categoryID Paramter on service.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I need to return data from allReportsubCategory based on report Category ID

but I face issue how to return data from allReportsubCategory based on reportcategoryID .

so How to write function return reports based on ReportCategoryID ?

```
allReportsubCategory:any[];
this.allReportsubCategory =[
    {
        "reportID": 1,
        "reportName": "xxx",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3,

    },
    {
        "reportID": 17,
        "reportName": "Jobs Monitor",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3
    },
    {
        "reportID": 2025,
        "reportName": "Old Tables Report",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3

    }];
```

on service.ts

```
 GetreportByCategoryId(reportCategoryID:string){
    return this.allReportsubCategory.??????

  }
```

so I need when pass 3 to function GetreportByCategoryId(reportcategoryID) return all data above based on 
reportcategoryid= 3

**updated post**

when call it on component as below

```
reportByCategoryId:any[]
 this.reportByCategoryId = this._displayreport.GetreportByCategoryId("3");
  console.log("data by category id" + this.reportByCategoryId )
```

no return for data above and console log as below :

data by category idundefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter the values in array by some condition you can use [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Also you need to use `number` type in this method due to `reportCategoryID` in provided data has number type.

```
GetreportByCategoryId(id: number) {
  return this.allReportsubCategory
    .filter(category => category.reportCategoryID === id);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.Dont post answer directly!.Let the op know why is this the solution

Comment: ok this is good and when call it on component I use subscribe or not

Comment: No need to subscribe unless the method returns observable

Comment: when call method on answer post 1 it give me undefined

Comment: so what is problem

Comment: problem data above not returned

Comment: when pass 3 to function it must return data json [
    {
        "reportID": 1,
        "reportName": "xxx",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3,

    },
    {
        "reportID": 17,
        "reportName": "Jobs Monitor",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3
    },
    {
        "reportID": 2025,
        "reportName": "Old Tables Report",
        "reportIndex": 1,
        "reportCategoryID": 3

    }];

Comment: because report caetgory id=3 exist on array

Comment: @ahmedbarbary Please, see updated answer. `find` method returns the finding object and `filter` method returns the array with objects that are passed the condition

Comment: thank you for reply it not return any thing I do that on stackbliz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-1arrvm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts on appcomponent.ts-ngoninit

Comment: @ahmedbarbary I got it. The problem is `reportCategoryID` in `this.allReportsubCategory` has number type. In `GetreportByCategoryId` method we pass string type and use strict comparison. So, the solution is to use == instead of === in filter or pass number type in `GetreportByCategoryId` I prefer to use the second variant